# Adding a twist to a card game which may probability wise make the game unfair

Tags: probability, card-games

My friends and I gathered to play a card game the other night. More than 15 people showed up, therefore we had to shuffle two decks of cards so everyone could play at the same time. The game generally begins by handing each player 5 cards, revealing one card on the ground and put the remaining cards facing down on the ground. Each player who cannot play or simply don’t want to according to what is revealed, should draw a card from the ground.

**Here is the twist**:
The table we were sitting around were a huge one, someone suggested to split the unrevealed portion of the cards in two after shuffling it so players can access it more easily where they need to no matter where they sit.

**And here is the question**:
In my opinion, it is not fair to split the cards on the ground, cause what if I needed a 4 to win the game and all 4s were in the half that was not mine to pick from.
This is just an initial thought without any proof to back it up.

***Can someone explain if I’m right or wrong? Can this person help me prove it?***

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is to decide what "fair" means. If it means "My chances of winning in the mixed-deck game should be the same as in the single-deck game," then your argument is certainly right, because sometimes all the 4s will be in the other pile. But equally often, they'll all be in *your* pile, and that's a good basis for thinking about a different notion of fairness.

Here's an alternative notion: the game is "fair" if no one would choose to switch positions with anyone else. That amounts to saying that it's "fair" of the odds of winning don't depend on where you're sitting. But **when** does the position-switching question get asked? If it's "after the cards have been dealt," then even the original game isn't "fair". because if you get dealt a rotten hand, you'd happily ask to switch with anyone else in the game, thinking "NO one can possibly have a worse mess than *this*!"

So the "swap places" question has to be asked before the deal. And I think that if you look at the current setup --- each player gets to draw from one of two piles --- you can see that everyone is equally disadvantaged in a randomly-dealt game (or over all possible randomly-dealt games).

If you're playing on a long oval table, and the folks at the ends have to use "their" pile, but folks in the middle can draw from *either* pile, then there *is* an unfairness...but I don't think that's what you were talking about.

It's useful to think about how we select a person for a prize or a task --- we "draw straws" --- one person holds several straws in their hand, all the same length except one -- and the others each draw a straw, leaving the 'dealer' with the last one. The person who draws the short straw wins (or loses). Now the loser may say "no fair!", but they actually had the same chance of getting the short straw as anyone else --- they only call it unfair when it turns out to be them. In short: fairness in games is probably best defined as "equal chance of winning at the start" rather than "everyone ends up with the same score". :)

Comment: I agree with you on the last point. More than mixing two decks of cards, the “unfairness” i was referring to was associated with splitting the unrevealed cards on the ground which each player is limited to pick from only one pile. When there is only one pile, I have same chance as everyone else to draw a card with an advantage in the game, but when it is splits in half, I may simply not have that or have double of it! By fair, I mean same chance of drawing cards with advantages from the ground for all players no matter where they are sitted.

Comment: On average, over all deals and all deck-splits, your chance of drawing the 4 of hearts is the same as anyone else's. In any *particular* deal and deck-split, your chances are indeed zero or twice the averageo-over-all-deals-and-splits. That's a little like the odds of your initial hand containing the ace of clubs once the cards are dealt in the one-deck game: on average, it's 5/52, but after the deal, it's either 0 (which happens 47/52 of the time) or 1 (which happens 5/52 of the time). That doesn't make the game unfair, unless you regard deal cards as "unfair."

Answer (score 0):

When you draw a card, it is equally likely to be any of the unseen cards. The probability of a drawn card being favorable is independent of the method of selection. In most games, this method is usually a single stockpile from which you are forced to take the topmost card when you draw. Distributing the undealt cards into multiple stockpiles will not alter the probability of a drawn card being favorable. The game remains fair because the distribution is impartial -- it does not favor any one player over any other.